# Virtualbox ubuntu mtd device must be supplied

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox

I am new to Linux so I dont know much on the fixes, I installed virtualbox and installed ubuntu 20.04
It doesn't boot, it only shows this error, I don't know what to do and I can't find any solution.
I already removed my machine and installed it again, It did boot about 3 times and then again I had the same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5tDK.png)

Comment: Whatever's going wrong with the VM, it's not that "mtd device" error - this is a rather common message that doesn't interfere with booting. Try updating VirtualBox if you can without risking anything, and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Also, what did you do to the VM those three times it did boot? Like, you got it to boot, what did you do in the VM once it was booted? Maybe a change you made one of those times is what's causing the issue now?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I've removed the [windows-subsystem-for-linux] tag, since you say you are using VirtualBox, which typically means you *aren't* using WSL.  If you really are using WSL, please feel free to add the tag back in, but also update your question with details on the interaction between VirtualBox and WSL.  Thanks!

Comment: Thankyou, I’ll try to update it, 
I downloaded it yesterday, first times(before removing it and installing it again) it was working fine but then I pressed the windows key and the screen went black and an error appeared and showed that error. I removed and added again the machine and it worked ok for a few times, y saved the machine state and turned off my laptop and when I turned it on and initialized again the virtual machine that error appeared again.